# Stardog not returning expected results upon query involving division

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, querying, stardog

this query is supposed to return the proportion of players in a specific competition that are of a certain team. 
However when I run it on my stardog db, nothing is returned. 
Stardog doesn't even indicate there were 0 results or fill in column headers. 
I pasted the query into yasgui.org's interface, and the query appears to be well formed (no syntax error). 
Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't return the expected results?

```
select ?competition ?team (COUNT(distinct ?team_1_player)/COUNT(distinct ?player) as ?proportion)
where {
    ?team_1_player prop:competesIn ?competition.
  ?team_1_player prop:memberOf ?team.
    ?player prop:competesIn ?competition.
}
group by ?competition ?team
order by desc(?proportion)
```

The following similar query does return expected results. It does exactly the same, except that it returns the sum of team players and of all players in the competition, instead of the proportion of players of a certain team.

```
select distinct ?competition ?team (COUNT(distinct ?team_1_player) as ?num_team_players) (COUNT(distinct ?player) as ?num_players)
where {
    ?team_1_player prop:competesIn ?competition.
  ?team_1_player prop:memberOf ?team.
    ?player prop:competesIn ?competition.
}
group by ?competition ?team
order by desc(?num_team_players)
```

Comment: The first query is more complex and I don't know how the query optimizer works. How big is your dataset? Maybe you get a timeout and there is some config option to increase that parameter. You could try to rewrite the query with sub-SELECTs but I'm not sure if this would help.

Comment: That said, your query looks correct, thus, I'd suggest to ask for support at the Stardog mailing list.

Comment: As a possible workaround, what happens if you add the division to the second query in terms of the variables?  E.g., add `(?a / ?b as ?proportion)`?

Comment: You should check your `stardog.log` file and if nothing is there, try running with the `--verbose` flag on the command line. And, as suggested, you should raise the issue on the mailing list

Comment: There was apparently an error with the data that was being queried, as it returns the expected result on a different dataset. I still haven't identified the issue with the data, but i wish stardog would have logged what was wrong. i will submit a suggestion to stardog when i've time.